# How do I fix ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl

I am trying to visit gimp.org using Chrome 89 on Windows 7. I get the `ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` error. I have looked at various stackexchange answers as well as several other resources and here is a list of the steps I have  tried:

- Verified the expiration date of the certificate (1/11/21 to 4/11/21, issued by R3)
- Tried a hard refresh
- Tried visiting gimp.org in "incognito" mode
- Cleared cache (images, files, cookies and other site data)
- `chrome://restart`
- Updated Chrome
- Cleared SSL Slate under Internet Options
- Uninstalled and reinstalled Chrome
- Disabled all extensions
- Verified that SSL Labs reports "A" for gimp.org
- Under `chrome://net-internals/#dns`, clicked "Clear Host Cache"
- Looked through all running processes and didn't see anything suspicious
- Disabled anti-virus

I tried visiting in Firefox and the error doesn't occur. I also tried on Chrome on another computer and the error doesn't occur.

So, the problem doesn't seem to be with the website, or with my browser, or with the certificate, or with my operating system. I don't know what else to try.

Comment: Which certificate authority has signed the certificate? A 3 month certificate is sort of weird

Comment: @Ramhound: *"A 3 month certificate is sort of weird"* - it is actually pretty standard with certificates issued by Let's Encrypt. And this specific certificate is issued by Let's Encrypt.

Comment: `chrome://restart` fixed the issue I had with my self signed certificate that I added to my Trusted Authorities

Answer (score 1):

From what you've described, your version of Windows 7 does not have the necessary CA certificates. As per the [Lets Encrypt certificate page](https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/), you can download it from the [IdenTrust download page](https://www.identrust.com/support/downloads), choose the [Root Certificate Download](https://www.identrust.com/node/935) under the "TrustID X3" section and double-click in Windows 7 to add it.

As an aside, [Windows 7 is no longer supported by Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-7-end-of-life-support-information) so it might be worth looking to upgrade in order to stay safe on the Internet.

Comment: I downloaded and installed the certificate but to no avail, unfortunately. I really prefer Windows 7 over Windows 10, but given the lack of support I may end up upgrading as you suggest...

Comment: Can you post the certificate chain that's failing? It's called the Certification Path in Windows 10 if that helps and you can get to it through the lock icon to the left of the website name in Chrome.